# How to determine the value of a variable causing a TypeError in a library?

Tags: python, debugging, typeerror

I want to be able to see what values are causing the TypeError to avoid reading the libraries code.

For Example my Traceback is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/censored/trunk/censored-cli/censored.py", line 945, in <module>
    detection(filelist, []) #empty options for now because we dont need any
  File "/censored/trunk/censored-cli/censored.py", line 770, in detection
    subprocess.run(analysis_cmd,env=env,check=True)
  File "/home/name/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/home/name/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/home/name/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1741, in _execute_child
    env_list.append(k + b'=' + os.fsencode(v))
  File "/home/name/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 810, in fsencode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

I would much rather see the value of filename on line 810 in fsencode, than to know it was interpreted as an int.

I know I can find fsencode in my install and change it to print the value, but I would prefer a built-in way to check the value of an error causing variable.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an IDE with an integrated debugger, like PyCharm.
2. Set a break point at the line of code which produces the error
3. Debug the program - it will stop at the break point and then you will see all the variables